# what is closed form of following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

> **What is closed form of following series?**
>   $$t^{(\frac{b}{2}-1)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(i^{b})^{n}t^{b(n-\frac{k}{2})}z^{k}}{k!Γ(b(n-\frac{k}{2})+\frac{b}{2})}$$

I solved a problem with two different methods. With the first method, the answer is given as follows:
$$e^{z}E_{b}(it),$$
where $E_{b}(it)$ is Mittag-Leffler function.
With the second method, I obtained the above series. Is this series equal to the answer obtained with the first method?

Comment: is $b$ integer ? positive ? or a real ?

Comment: **b is arbitrary real number**

Comment: Do you define $(i^b)^n$ as $e^{nb\pi i/2}$?

Comment: **If this is the case, can the series be written as closed form?**